# Stuck with moq and unit test for Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, moq

I'm trying to write unit tests for exist project. I always get SignStatus.Success and ModelState.Valid. I know how to deal with model state by add model error in test, will give me invalid model. But i don't know why i have success in sign in all cases. Login Action is default, here is:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return View(model);

    // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
    // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, change to shouldLockout: true
    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) || !Url.IsLocalUrl(returnUrl))
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            return Redirect(returnUrl);
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return RedirectToAction("SendCode", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = model.RememberMe });
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

And there is my test:

```
[Test]
public async Task LogInSuccessAndReturnViewAsync()
{
    LoginViewModel loginView = new LoginViewModel { Email = "qwe@asd", Password = "123", RememberMe = false };
    //Arrange
    //User.Identity
    var validUser = new Mock<IIdentity>();  
    moqContext.Setup(x => x.User.Identity).Returns(validUser.Object);
    validUser.Setup(x => x.Name).Returns(loginView.Email);

    //ApplicationUserManager
    var user = new ApplicationUser { UserInfo = new UserInfo {
        Id = 336,
        FirstName = "User",
        LastName ="Info",
        CountryId = 1,
        City = null,
        Address = null,
        ZipCode = null,
        Tel = null,
        Position = null,
        PayoutTime = 0,
        LanguageId = 3,
        PayPalAllowIR = false,
        LiqPayAllowIR = false
    } };
    var userStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>(MockBehavior.Strict);
    userStore.As<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>().Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>())).ReturnsAsync(user);
    var userManager = new Mock<ApplicationUserManager>(userStore.Object);

    //ApplicationSignInManager
    var authenticationManager = new Mock<IAuthenticationManager>();
    var signInManager = new Mock<ApplicationSignInManager>(userManager.Object, authenticationManager.Object);

    accountController = new AccountController(userManager.Object, signInManager.Object);
    var context = new ControllerContext(moqContext.Object, new System.Web.Routing.RouteData(), accountController);
    accountController.ControllerContext = context;

    //Act
    var res = await accountController.Login(loginView,"/Account/Login");

    //Assert
    Assert.IsNotNull(res);
}
```

What i do wrong?

Comment: So what exactly are you trying to test? That `AccountController.Login` returns not null?

Comment: i can't test this because i had NullReferenceException. I want to test, that user's credentials correct and user can logIn then redirect to "Index", "Home". Or incorrect credentials

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you don't setup `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` method in your mock, it will always return the default value for output which is `SignInStatus.Success`

If you want other return value for your test you need to setup your `SignInManager` instance.

```
signInManager
    .Setup(x => x.PasswordSignInAsync(It.IsAny<string>(),
                                      It.IsAny<string>(),
                                      It.IsAny<bool>(),
                                      It.IsAny<bool>()))
         .ReturnsAsync(Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.SignInStatus.Failure);
```

Comment: It works. Am i need to setup returns status for all cases without depending which model i pass in action?

Comment: It depends on your tests. do you really want to mock `SignInManager`? the input for `SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` doesn't matter

Comment: i'm new in unit testing and moq framework. i don't know how to deal with it. but almost of all actions in controller use SignInManager and UserManager. And methods like User.Identity.GetUserId(), UserManager.FindById(); Could you recommend some articles, books, or courses/tutorials to better understand how it's work?

Comment: I can't think of any specific source right now. You should check out channel9.msdn.com and mva.microsoft.com

Comment: Ok. Thank you. But could you explain me, why input for SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync doesn't matter?

Comment: because if you use my sample code, you setup `PasswordSignInAsync` to return `SignInStatus.Failure` for any string as input

Comment: Is it good practice to test for any string or tests like this should have correct input ? I'm a little bit confused.

Comment: It all depends on your needs and how you want to mock your object

Comment: Directly in this test, is it better to test with correct input? Or can you show me example with correct input? What it should be?